# Include libheif as an external dependency into project using cmake

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to include [libheif](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif) into my project using cmake. Libheif is more complicated than what I've worked with before because it requires you externally build and include libde265.

### Attempt #1:

I have used vcpkg to export pre-built binary packages, this creates a directory called libheif which includes everything here:

```
+---bin
|       heif.dll
|       libde265.dll
|       libx265.dll
|       libx265.pdb
|       
+---debug
|   +---bin
|   |       heif.dll
|   |       libde265.dll
|   |       libx265.dll
|   |       libx265.pdb
|   |       
|   \---lib
|       |   heif.lib
|       |   libde265.lib
|       |   libx265.lib
|       |   x265-static.lib
|       |   
|       \---pkgconfig
|               libheif.pc
|               x265.pc
|               
+---include
|   |   x265.h
|   |   x265_config.h
|   |   
|   +---libde265
|   |       de265.h
|   |       
|   \---libheif
|           heif.h
|           
+---lib
|   |   heif.lib
|   |   libde265.lib
|   |   libx265.lib
|   |   x265-static.lib
|   |   
|   \---pkgconfig
|           libheif.pc
|           x265.pc
|           
+---share
|   +---libde265
|   |       copyright
|   |       libde265Config-debug.cmake
|   |       libde265Config-release.cmake
|   |       libde265Config.cmake
|   |       libde265ConfigVersion.cmake
|   |       vcpkg_abi_info.txt
|   |       
|   +---libheif
|   |   |   copyright
|   |   |   libheif-config-debug.cmake
|   |   |   libheif-config-release.cmake
|   |   |   libheif-config-version.cmake
|   |   |   libheif-config.cmake
|   |   |   vcpkg_abi_info.txt
|   |   |   
|   |   \---.vs
|   |           ProjectSettings.json
|   |           slnx.sqlite
|   |           
|   \---x265
|           copyright
|           vcpkg_abi_info.txt
|           
\---tools
    +---libde265
    |       dec265.exe
    |       enc265.exe
    |       libde265.dll
    |       
    \---x265
            x265.exe
```

(There were more headers, I removed them because one illustrates the point) I put folder `libheif` in my external folder in my project. Then in `CMakeLists.txt` I have tried using

`target_link_libraries(my_project ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/libheif/lib/heif)`

that then fails looking for `heif.obj` file that is not there. It does find the dlls though.

After that failed, I tried again, this time using the .cmake files in the share directory:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/libheif/share/libheif)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/libheif/share/libde265)

include(libheif-config)
include(libde265Config)
```

This I get unresolved external symbol when trying to use anything in libheif.

### Attempt #2:

I tried including libeheif by adding it as a submodule `git submodule add https://github.com/strukturag/libheif.git external/libheif`
and then in `CMakeLists.txt` I added:

```
include_directories(external/libheif/include)
include_directories(external/libheif/include/libheif)
include_directories(external/libheif/include/libde265)
add_subdirectory(external/libheif)
target_link_libraries(my_project libheif)
```

This results in unresolved external symbols whenever I try to use anything in the libheif library.

### Other information

- The only successful thing I have been able to do is include the headers directory so intellisence recognizes when I `#include <heif.h>`
- I have looked all over on how to include dll and libraries, but all the results either need me to use the cmake GUI, which I am not sure I can because I'm working on this project with other people and I want to make sure it works on their computer without having to use the cmake GUI.
- Same with just using vcpkg to include it, I dont want my teammates to have to use it as well, I need to just use CMakeLists.txt
- [This tutorial](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/Exporting-and-Importing-Targets#importing-targets) would be helpful but the generate stuff is above my head and I couldnt find what it meant by generate. It might be a rabbit hole I loose a day over.
- I am working on Windows 10, I will eventually need to make it so it can build on OSX but I'm just trying to get it to work on windows for now.

I am trying to understand why each of these approaches failed. I would rather go down the path of attempt #2 because I feel like that is better for down the road when I need to make it compile for mac as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Then in CMakeLists.txt I have tried using：
> target_link_libraries(my_project
> ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/libheif/lib/heif)

I think you should use:

```
target_link_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE ./external/libheif/lib/heif
)

target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    heif
    xxx
)
```

> target_link_directories : Add link directories to a target.

Comment: what is the xxx?

Comment: alas, I run into the same error as before `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\external\libheif\lib\heif.obj' [C:\Users\me\Desktop\my_project\my_project_api\build\my_project_api.vcxproj]
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\external\libheif\lib\heif.obj' [C:\Users\me\Desktop\my_project\my_api\build\my_project_cli.vcxproj]`